# Why is the assignment operator affecting all elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
waiting = [[0]]* 5 # we can assume the waiting to contain 5 lists
print((np.shape(waiting))) # (5, 1)
waiting[0][0] = waiting[0][0] + (0.72) # only the value at the first list should get changed
print(waiting) # [[0.72], [0.72], [0.72], [0.72], [0.72]] when I expected only the first list's 0 
                # to become 0.72
```

As explained in the comments, why is all of the array getting affected by the 3rd line `waiting[0][0] = waiting[0][0] + (0.72)`

Comment: Because there is only one list: you did *not* make five copies of the list, you made a list that contains the *same* sublist five times.

Comment: Note, you are not using `numpy-ndarray` objects here, but a Python list that contains other lists.